# Catching all errors in PHP

Tags: php

I want to catch all errors and, depending on its type, do some sort of operations. I'd like to handle the following types of errors:

- notices
- warnings
- errors
- critical errors
- alerts
- emergencies

Can I do these with set_error_handler() function?

And is there any difference between E_USER_WARNING and E_WARNING?

Comment: For most you can, but handle with care, because you will probably change your applications execution flow and therefore the behaviour. I've seen scary situations, where the application just "go on" after an error... Btw: Why don't you just read the logs?

Comment: Check the Manual:**Example #1 Using error handling in a script**

Comment: "alerts" and "emergencies" are not earmarked for, but all other PHP error/message types can be handled, yes.

Comment: You already asked that question. Investigate the answer before you ask the next one!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example derived from [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.examples.php):

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
set_error_handler('handle_error', E_ALL);
function handle_error($errno, $errmsg, $filename, $linenum, $vars) {
    $errors = array(
        E_ERROR              => 'Error',
        E_WARNING            => 'Warning',
        E_PARSE              => 'Parsing Error',
        E_NOTICE             => 'Notice',
        E_CORE_ERROR         => 'Core Error',
        E_CORE_WARNING       => 'Core Warning',
        E_COMPILE_ERROR      => 'Compile Error',
        E_COMPILE_WARNING    => 'Compile Warning',
        E_USER_ERROR         => 'User Error',
        E_USER_WARNING       => 'User Warning',
        E_USER_NOTICE        => 'User Notice',
        E_STRICT             => 'Runtime Notice',
        E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  => 'Catchable Fatal Error'
    );
    if(in_array($errno, array_keys($errors))) {
        echo $errors[$errno];
    }
}
$foo = NOT_DEFINED;
```

It will output the error type.